# Converting from SQL Server to MySQL - MERGE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm converting Stored Procedures from SQL Server to MySQL and I've found a query that has me stumped:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.T_ExampleTable WHERE Col1 = @Col1 AND Col2 = @Col2 AND Col3 = @Col3)
    SET @return_value = -10
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.T_ExampleTable WHERE Col1 = @Col1 OR Col2 = @Col2 OR Col3 = @Col3)
    SET @return_value = -20;

IF @return_value = 0
BEGIN
    MERGE ExampleDB.dbo.T_ExampleTable AS T
    USING (VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, @Col3)) AS S (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    ON T.Col1 = S.Col1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (S.Col1, S.Col2, S.Col3);
END
```

For security purposes, I have altered the names of variables but the syntax is the same.

I think I have a grasp on what's happening with the `MERGE` here (but please correct me if I'm wrong). I assume that we're taking our 3 variables (`@Col1`, `@Col2`, and `@Col3`) and placing them in a result set we call "S". Then, we're checking each row in `T_ExampleTable` for a matching `Col1` value. Finally, we're saying if it DOESN'T match in any of the rows, `INSERT` these values.

Now, I'm not too familiar with the `MERGE` syntax, so I may be off with the above assumption. Assuming I'm correct, however, isn't this the same as just performing a `SELECT FROM T_ExampleTable WHERE Col1 = @Col1`, then checking the `@@ROWCOUNT` (or `FOUND_ROWS()` in MySQL) and if it doesn't equal 0, performing an `INSERT`?

Furthermore, I am even more baffled by logic above the `MERGE`. If my understanding of how `MERGE` works is correct (and again, it may be off) then the entire statement is pointless. Because basically, if `@Col1` exists within the `T_ExampleTable`, then `@return_value` is going to equal -10 or -20. Thus, it can't equal 0 and we won't hit the `MERGE`. If `@Col1` does not exist within `T_ExampleTable`, then `@return_value` is going to equal 0, but the `MERGE` isn't going to return any result set since `T.Col1 = S.Col1` will never be true.

This is why I believe I must be misunderstanding something about how `MERGE` works. Either that, or the SQL Server code I'm porting is just poorly written (which is also possible, I guess).

So ultimately, I'm looking for two answers here. One that helps clarify what the logic of a `MERGE` statement is and if my understanding of the above code is correct, and another that shows the possible solution for converting this to MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For practical purposes, I think this is equivalent to this (in both databases):

```
INSERT INTO T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM (SELECT @Col1 as col1, @Col2 as col2, @Col3 as col3) s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ExampleDB.dbo.T_ExampleTable t
                      WHERE t.col1 = s.col1
                     );
```

There may be some edge cases where they are not exactly the same -- say, in terms of concurrent calls to the stored procedure or when `col1` is `NULL`.  But you already have differences in locking between the two databases anyway.

(And, although you didn't ask, I would expect Postgres to be a more natural database to switch to from SQL Server because Postgres and SQL Server have a larger overlap in functionality.)

Comment: Thank you for your super fast reply! From what I can tell, this does seem to at the very least return 0/1 rows based on whether or not a matching Col1 exists. However, it skips the part of the insert. While I'm not totally clueless so I could figure that out on my own, I was wondering if you could comment on the code above the `MERGE` as well? Was I wrong about my understanding that the entire procedure was pointless?